# On a graph, can the compositions of both the x and y variables involve the unit time?

Tags: spacetime, time

Time seems to be so fundamental to the calculations that we make, that it seems to be at the core of everything we do.

Indeed, this is not just philosophically true, time is very often the x axis, by convention, and we consider its distance from 0, in respect to some variable y, and amongst others if you go into more than 2 dimensions. Furthermore, whilst time isn't always explicitly the x axis, I always find that time is a composite of either variables x or y, but never x and y.

Is this possible though? Can time be part of both variables x and y, or is it always confined to one variable alone? Furthermore, what if you are working with say, 5 dimensions (which I have never ever done, for the record), could time form the basis of 2 variables plotted against the other 3?

As a side note, the driving force for this question is not to see whether more (or less) can be achieved by doing this, (if it's even possible), I just find this to be mathematically and scientifically fascinating, as it seems to be a feature of the underlying fabric of maths and science.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite common to use time to parameterise an equation.

For example suppose you have a particle moving in a circle (or radius $r$). One way of describing its motion would be to say the trajectory describing its motion is:

$$ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \tag{1} $$

but an alternative description would be to use the pair of equations:

$$\begin{align}
x &= r\cos\omega t \\
y &= r\sin\omega t
\end{align}$$

where $t$ is elapsed time. If you calculate values of $x$ and $y$ for $t$ starting at zero and going up to $t = 2\pi/\omega$ you'll find you get a circle just like equation (1). So not only do these equations give you the same curve as equation (1) but they give extra information about the rate at which the particle moves round the circle.

Writing the equations like this is known as [parameterisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation), and it's widely done in physics, for example spacetime trajectories in relativitity are commonly written as four parametric equations $(t(\tau), x(\tau), y(\tau), z(\tau))$ where the parameter $\tau$ is the proper time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether there can be more than one time dimension, that's hard to answer. It's unclear how to reformulate physics to accommodate more than one time dimension in any field, except for maybe special relativity.

In special relativity, time is "just like" a space dimension, except it has a minus sign in the metric. As a result, you can easily formulate special relativity in $m$ space dimensions and $n$ time dimensions, ignoring all philosophical issues of what "multiple time dimensions" really means. Then you can replace $3$ and $1$ where they appear in some conventional equations with $m$ and $n$.

Due to some technical results about partial differential equations, it turns out that having more than one time dimension makes the solutions badly behaved, so that it's impossible to always predict (approximately) what will happen in the future given approximate knowledge of what's happening now. Since this is another way to describe what physics itself is, that means physics is impossible.

For much more detail, see [Max Tegmark's paper](http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/dimensions.pdf).